# run .sql files from within sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Any idea on how I could run a bunch of .sql files that contains lots of functions from within sqlalchemy, after I create the schema ? I've tried using `DDL()`, `engine.text(<text>).execute()`, `engine.execute(<text>)`. None of them work, they are either failing because improper escape or some other weird errors. I am using sqlalchemy 0.6.6

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. You must parse the file and split it into individual SQL commands, and then execute each one separately in a transaction.